# How short is "short monograph"?

Tags: non-fiction, academic-writing

I've seen several references to some "short monograph on *subject X"*. But how short is that? Is there a standard length to use as a reference?

I realize that this depends on page size and font, so I guess answers should reference what kind of layout is used.

Comment: I think many of us have wondered how long Holmes's trifling monographs were. :)

Answer (score 2):

Monograph lengths are generally not about number of pages, but about word counts. In the humanities you will find monographs ranging from 5000-100,000 (and even longer) in length. There is no standard length for monographs unless you are writing for a specific publisher/publication which specifies length.

Answer (score 0):

I think the shortest monograph (as in the Stanford Briefs or Palgrave Pivot series) would be about 20,000 words.

Comment: On what basis? This answer is not useful without argument of evidence.